# Can not reference a variable in enclosing loop statement

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, scope

Ok so here is the new code that appends a table however it is running ALL of the final for in loop on the final td2 rather than running it on each td2 each instance of the loop.

This is the full function updated:

```
function createRooms() {
    i = 0;
    var tbl = document.createElement("table");

    for (room in rooms) {
        i++;

        var rowid = "row" + i;
        var mytable = document.getElementById("lado");

        var tr = mytable.insertRow();
        tr.id = rowid; tr.className = 'row-cont';   

        var leftid = "title-cell-" + i;
        var rightid = "beds-cell-" + i;

        var td1 = tr.insertCell();
        var td2 = tr.insertCell();
        td1.id = leftid; td1.className = 'room-title-cell';
        td2.id = rightid; td2.className = 'room-beds-cell';


        for (var j = 0; j < rooms[j].beds; j++ ) {

            var bedtable = td2.appendChild(tbl);
            var bedid = (rowid +  "-" + j);

            var bedrow = bedtable.insertRow();
            bedrow.id = bedid; bedrow.className = 'bed-cont';

            for (var b = 1; b < daysThisMonth; b++) {
                var bedcellid = bedid + "-" + b;

                var bedcell = bedrow.insertCell();
                bedcell.id = bedcellid; bedcell.className = 'bed-cell ' + "c" + b ;
            };

        };

    };

};
```

Comment: You're trying to insert a row inside of a cell

Comment: you should look if this tr.insertCell() is returning correct object.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this API, but it seems weird that a cell would have a method to insert a row.

Comment: You cannot insert a row inside of a cell. That's like putting a cellphone in a microchip.

Comment: @MightyPork there is no API...

Comment: Christ, I have done this a bunch of times with html i guess its not correct syntax, I will try adding another tbody within the cell and see once I have fixed it post the reply.

Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Of course it is API, there's no cells and rows in JavaScript itself.

Comment: @lombausch yes i didnt post the html but that bit of code is doing its job.

Comment: @MightyPork I guess that depends on your enterpretation of the definition. JavaScript inside of a web browser has native access to the Document Object Model (DOM) and these methods are simply DOM extensions of specific elements, all specified using W3C standards. This includes all of the functions he's using. The answer is quite simple. You simply cannot put a row inside of a cell. You need to create a table first to put the row in then put the table in the cell. But that seems pointless.

Comment: @MightyPork Apparently Document Object Model (DOM) is an Application Programming Interface (API) so technically I am incorrect but I will admit that. I should have known to be honest but JavaScript actually only exists because of web browsers for use with the DOM so maybe you could see how I would be mistaken. Just so you know though those methods are in fact standard in web browsers.

Comment: Interpretation* lol *cell* phone won't let me edit my comment. Damn touch screen. Lmao

Comment: Ok guys - its 12:20 am my time now and i must admit I'm waning.
I have solved the row problem by putting a table inside the cell - but it is running the last for loop only on the last td2 so it has all of the rows and cells inside.

It isn't running the entire function once, it seems to be running the top for in loop four times then running the final for loop on the last instance.

html it is creating:

Comment: Ok guys - its 12:20 am my time now and i must admit I'm waning.
I have solved the row problem by putting a table inside the cell - but it is running the last for loop only on the last td2 so it has all of the rows and cells inside.

It isn't running the entire function once, it seems to be running the top for in loop four times then running the final for loop on the last instance.

Cant paste the code here as its too long

Comment: Now you're just trying to put a table inside of itself. You should be creating new table elements. As for the rest of the logic of your code that's for you to figure out. FYI if you want me to be able to get your reply from your post you'll need to tag me. Use the @ symbol as the start of your comment followed by the user's name without spaces to direct the rest of that comment to the person.

Comment: @JonathanGray Thanks for that John, I will have another look today see what is going on. As for the table, the table element is a new element its just inside a cell - which is completely legit.

Once I have the solution I will also try and frame an answer that actually makes sense and can be searched.

Once again thanks for your time.